# Comportamiento no esperado con la anotación @RequestScope

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, scope

Soy nuevo con la tecnología Spring y haciendo pruebas con el controlador me encuentro que si lo anoto con @RequestScope y hago peticiones a dicho controlador debuggeando compruebo que como era de esperar la instancia del controlador va cambiando en cada petición sin embargo el contenido de la propiedad publica **texto** que recoge su valor de un formulario va manteniendo su valor (de tal forma que en las distintas llamadas a mostrarFormulario se van concatenando el texto que me llega en la request con los distintos textos introducidos anteriormente). ¿Como es esto posible? Es como si las distintas instancias del controlador compartiesen el valor de dicha propiedad.

```
@Controller
@RequestScope
@RequestMapping("/prueba")
public class ControladorPrueba {
  public String texto;
  
  @RequestMapping(path="/mostrarFormulario")
  private String showControlador() 
  {  
    return "formularioPrueba";  
  }
  
  @RequestMapping(path="/mostrarTexto", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  private String showData(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) 
  { 
     if (texto==null) texto=""; 
     texto=texto+request.getParameter("texto");
     model.addAttribute("texto",texto);
     return "verResultado"; 
  }
```

Comment: He sustituido ```@RequestScope``` por ```@Scope("request")``` y ya obtengo el comportamiento esperado. Es curioso por que en el siguiente enlace https://blog.marcnuri.com/spring-bean-scopes-guia-rapida se especifica explícitamente que para los beans basados en ```@Component``` se utiliza el ```@RequestScope```. Por si es un dato de importancia la versión de Spring que estoy utilizando es la 5.1.4.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que la instancia de *ControladorPrueba* es distinta pero el valor de *texto* es el mismo? Suena muy raro, ya no sería problema de Spring sino de la propia JVM, a no ser que por algún motivo en cada petición envíes el mismo texto (aunque pareces tener suficiente experiencia como para haber descartado esa posibilidad).

Comment: En todo caso, para añadir nueva información a la pregunta suele ser mejor editarla y modificarla que añadir un comentario. Bienvenido a SOe.

Comment: Efectivamente lo que quiero decir es eso que la instancia del ControladorPrueba es distinta pero el valor de texto se mantiene en cada Request de tal forma que al llamar al jsp mostrarResultado se muestran todos los textos concatenados que se han ido introduciendo en el formulario en las distintas rerquest. Con @Scope("request") me funciona y en texto solo aparecerá el ultimo texto introducido.

Answer (score 0):

Tras un rato investigando he añadido la linea `System.out.println(this.getClass());` en el código del método `showData()` comprobando que retorna en el caso de que el controlador lleve la anotación `@RequestScope`
***class com.spring.mvc.PruebaController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7fabd5a***
mientras que en el caso de que lleve la anotación `@Request` a secas me imprime
***class com.spring.mvc.PruebaController***.
Esta diferencia de comportamiento se debe a que en el caso de la anotación `@RequestScope` Spring encapsula a mi controlador en un objeto proxy lo cual hace que tenga el comportamiento no deseado que he descrito. Tal y como había indicado en un comentario de respuesta con la anotación `@Request` el comportamiento es el deseado, la propiedad **texto** se me reinicia en cada petición.
Para asegurar que la anotacion `@RequestScope` no encapsule en un objeto proxy al controlador lo debemos indicar explicitamente en la anotación de la siguiente forma:

@RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)

No domino el tema de la encapsulación en objetos proxy pero el hecho de que al reproducir el error obtenía el mismo texto en distintas instancias del objeto proxy me lleva a pensar que aunque los proxies sean distintos el objeto encapsulado es el mismo. No me acaba de quedar claro pues la ventaja de usar objetos proxies en estos casos.